# NSFetchRequest for 2-way to-many Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I recently started using CoreData and ran into a complicated (at least to me) fetch that I could not figure out. I searched around but had a hard time coming up with good terminology to search with, and thus had no results that sufficed. Here is a basic example of my coredata model:

[image]

What I am trying to do is execute a fetch to get all of the **Persons that are a member of a particular Club**. Example: *get all of the members from the Chess Club*. I could do this easily with SQL (have a third table that represents PersonInClub, do two joins to combine the two tables, and Select all the Persons Where Club.name = 'Chess Club') but I am struggling to implement this with a fetch request.

My ultimate goal is to write an `NSFetchRequst` for an `NSFetchedRequestController`. This is why I cannot just do a fetch for the Club with the name `Chess Club` and then grab all of the members (unless I am misunderstanding something, can you do this and put the results in a controller?).

Any insights are much appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the current code for my NSFetchedResultController. Not sure how this will help though:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];


    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];    
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    // This will give me the chess club but I want it's members!
    // I tried things like @"[self.name = %@ members]" and stuff to try and retrieve the members as the results
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.name = %@", @"Chess Club"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // an array with just the Chess Club in it
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    // Printing the members, The members are correct but again, they are not attached to the Controller, the actual club is
    NSSet *members = [results.lastObject members];
    NSMutableArray *memberNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:members.count];
    for (Person *p in [members allObjects])
        [memberNames addObject:p.firstName];
    NSLog(@"All Members: %@", memberNames); // prints all of the members accurantely

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: you should setup predicate for request like: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any clubs.name == %@", @"Chess Club"]; Or if you already have Chess club enitity you don't need for request, you already got it -> club.members

Comment: @NeverBe I know that but how could I then put that into an `NSFetchedRequestController` instead of just receiving an `NSSet`?

Comment: You can init NSFetchedRequestController with request that have predicate. Is it mandatory to use NSFetchedRequestController?. Better show your code.

Comment: @NeverBe I added the code I am using to create the `NSFetchedRequestController` I attempted to comment the code so you can see what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well after far to long I eventually figured it out. It was actually quite simple, I used for following code (I have included extra code to help clarify the question and answer):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:NO];    
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

// This is the important part
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY self.clubs.name = %@", @"Chess Club"];
//

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Just to clarify received data
NSArray *allStudentsInChessClub = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];


NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

// My NSFetchedResultsController with students from the Chess Club
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
```

I assumed this would not work because I thought it would be attempting to access the property `name` from the `NSSet` not the values in the set. This returned all of the of the members in the Chess Club, not the Chess Club itself!

Comment: If you want search for a Club entity than use Club entity ,not Person!     [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Club" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

Comment: `clubs` in `self.clubs.name` is a to-many relationship that contains many `Club` objects. I want all of the `Persons` in a specific club named Chess Club and every person can be in multiple clubs. This "loops" through all of the clubs a person is in and adds them to the array if they are in the Chess Club. This allows me to use an NSFetchedRequestController instead of just executing a normal fetch request. I believe your method would only work if each `Person` was limited to one club

Comment: you are still confusing me. what you have and what you want to have? main question is what is source data you have for make a request? and what data data should be in NSFetchedRequestController?

Comment: @NeverBe My source data is a club name (in this case Chess Club). The data I want are all of the people in that club. I have added extra information to my answer to help clarify what I was looking for. If you have another solution, I am all ears!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Club" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];    
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

// This is the important part
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", @"Chess Club"];
//

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Just to clarify received data
Club *club = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] lastObject];
```

// all club members can be accessible by club.member property. If you search for one club, you do not need for NSFetchedResultsController, i think.

P.S. I recommend you to use MagicalRecord framework. (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)
In this case your code will reduce to 1 line of code:

```
Club *club = [Club MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"name" withValue:@"Chess Club"];
NSLog(@"club members %@", club.members);
```

Comment: My issue was not as much about getting the club members but rather about getting them into an `NSFetchedResultController`. Is there a way to do this through your example? I want an NSFetchedResultsController because the `Person` objects will be displayed in a tableview. The `Person` contains much more information then listed above, but I stripped it out for simplicities sake. Since the table will be changing frequently I wanted the benefit of `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: you code from topic with NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY self.clubs.name = %@", @"Chess Club"];
should work